# Fading out SVG filter on background image

Tags: css, svg, background-image, svg-filters

I have a collection of elements with background images that have an SVG filter on them making the background image grayish. I need it so that when you hover over that element, that SVG filter fades to transparent so the original color image shows with out the filter. Unfortunately, I can't seem to accomplish this. Here is the CSS:

```
.badge__image {
    background-position: center;
    filter: url(/dist/filter.svg#duotone_bluetan);
}
.badge__image:hover {
    -webkit-transition : -webkit-filter 1000ms ease;
    transition: filter 1000ms ease;
    filter: url(/dist/filter.svg#clear);;
}
```

No matter how I do it, the transition is instant. The image does have to be a background image, and I need to accomplish this SVG filter transition somehow. I'm not super proficient with SVG filtering or animations and I can't find a single example online of this being done. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

So I'm sticking a copy of the element inside of itself, and positioning it absolutely and fading out the inside element. This works one way, it fades to the parent background, however, once not hovering, the opacity of the inside element instantly jumps to 1 with no transition. What am I missing here?

```
.badge__image-filter {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-position: center;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms !important;
    transition: all 1000ms !important;
    filter: url(/dist/filter.svg#duotone_bluetan);
}
.badge__image-filter:hover {
    opacity: 0 !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms !important;
    transition: all 1000ms !important;
}
```

Comment: if you can express your filter in CSS filter shorthand (sepia, hue-rotate etc.) then you can transition them. You can't directly transition an SVG filter that's referenced from CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are asking your CSS transition to transition between one `url()` value to an other. For what's the CSS engine is aware of, these are just string values and aren't transition-able.

There are various ways you could achieve what you want.

One of them would be to duplicate your element, place both absolutely and apply each filter on its own element, and then transition both element's `opacity`.

```css
#clear,#filtered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
#filtered {
  filter: url(#blurMe);
}
#clear {
  opacity: 0;
}
#cont {
  position: relative;
}
#cont:hover #filtered {
  opacity: 0;
}
#cont:hover #clear {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute;pointer-events:none">
  <filter id="blurMe">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5">
    </feGaussianBlur>
  </filter>
</svg>
<div id="cont">
  <div id="filtered">Hello</div>
  <div id="clear">Hello</div>
</div>
```

An other one, depending on your actual filter, would be to use SMIL inside your SVG filter:

```css
#circ {
  filter: url(#blurMe);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute;pointer-events:none">
  <filter id="blurMe">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5">
      <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stdDeviation" to="0"
        dur="1s" fill="freeze" begin="circ.mouseover"/>
      <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stdDeviation" to="5"
        dur="1s" fill="freeze" begin="circ.mouseout"/>
    </feGaussianBlur>
  </filter>
</svg>

<div id="circ">Hello</div>
```

But this seems to work only in Firefox and Safari...

And I should note that if you are able to convert your SVG filter to a pure CSS one (using only CSS <filterFuncs>), then you can transition through their values, with the one gotcha that you have to maintain the order of all your filters between the two states ; that is, you can not transition from `blur(5px)` to `sepia(100%)`, you must transition from `blur(5px) sepia(0)` to `blur(0) sepia(100%)`.

```css
#circ {
  transition: filter 1s;
  color: red;
  filter: blur(5px) grayscale(100%);
}
#circ:hover {
  filter: blur(0px) grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="circ">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying the opacity trick, and it's almost working. I'm updating my question, maybe you can help.

Comment: @jrothafer I added a snippet example for the stacked version.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get the opacity working. I wanted to avoid this solution but oh well :)